# How to clone and remove while scrolling?

Tags: jquery

I know there are a lot of clone/remove posts on here. I just spent awhile clicking through a ton of them but none of them fit my situation.

Essentially I need to create new elements to make sure one is always visible in the parent container.

I am able to clone/add new elements but every time I try and remove old/out of view elements, it stops appending.

I am sure it is something simple but it escapes me! Eventually the speed will increase and leaving it as it is will create THOUSANDs of .box elements, so I am trying to cleaning out the old ones.

I did try just shuffling them, moving the first to the end but when the scroll speed increases that doesn't work. Any suggestions would be super helpful! Thank! :)

Code:

```
let counter = 0;
let clone;
function run() {
    if ($(".wrapper").find(".box").last().position().left < 400) {
        $(".wrapper").find(".box").last()
            .clone().insertAfter(".box")
    }

    if ($(".wrapper").find(".box").length > 3) {
        $(".wrapper").find(".box").each(function(ind, box) {
        if ($(box).position().left < -400) {
            // $(box).remove()
            }
        });
        }

            $(".box").css("transform", `translateX(${(counter -= 10)}px)`);
    }

    let int = setInterval(function() {
        run();
    }, 100);
```

https://codepen.io/kmarmet/pen/ReXPNO?editors=0010